# Integrating a square's perimeter to get its area

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to wrap my head around some integration applications.

I went through the exercise of integrating the circumference of a circle, $2*\pi*r$, to get the area of a circle.  I simply used the power rule and get $\pi*r^2$.

However when I extend this to a square,  I calculate the length around a square via $4*L$.  However using the power rule I end up with $2*L^2$ which is not the

Comment: The integral of $4L$ is $2L^2$ not $L^4$.

Comment: @akaitora `$2 \pi r$` renders as $2 \pi r$.  `$\pi r^2$` renders as $\pi r^2$.  For more information on how to format your questions/answers, see [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Right! That was a silly mistake.  However $2L^2$ is not $L^2$.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Consider a square such that the distance from the centre to any side is $r$. Then the area of the square is $4r^2$, and the perimeter of the square is $8r$, which is the derivative of $4r^2$.

So your circle rule works for the square, if we use the right parameter to describe its size.

**Exploration:** Let us play the same game with an equilateral triangle $T$. Again use as parameter $r$ the distance from the centre of $T$ to a side. Drop a perpendicular from the centre to a side, and join the centre to a vertex on that side. We get a $30$-$60$-$90$ triangle. Using this triangle we find that the perimeter of $T$ is $6\sqrt{3}r$, and its area is $3\sqrt{3}r^2$. Again the derivative of area is the perimeter.

The same pattern holds for all regular polygons. I will leave it to you to write out the argument, either by scaling (better) or by computation.

Comment: I will be going to sleep soon. If you have further questions, do ask, but there will be no response until tomorrow.

Comment: I understand that $dP/8$ works out to be the border width however I want to gain insight as to where the 8 is coming from.  Does 8 mean all 8 sides between the internal and external squares?

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't make any sense to me.  If I have a square whose side is 2 and the inner square has a side of 1, $dL = 1$ because $2-1 = 1$ however $1*0.5 \neq 8$.  What am I missing?

Comment: One half of $dL$ is $dL/2$, in your example $1/2$.

Comment: The length of the comment string is getting out of hand. I will delete all but the last couple of them,  and suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The length of a side, $L$, is analogous to the *diameter* of a circle, not its radius.  So the appropriate variable to use is $\ell=L/2$, in which case the perimeter is $8\ell$, which integrates to $4\ell^2$, and that *is* correct, since $4\ell^2=(2\ell)^2=L^2$.

(Remark:  I posted this before reading Andre Nicolas's answer.  It's basically the same.  But maybe the first sentence here is helpful.)

Comment: Thanks Barry!  That makes complete sense!

Comment: How do I simplify $4*r^2$ to $L^2$ where $L = 2r$ ?

Comment: @akaitora, $4=2^2$, so $4\ell^2=2^2\ell^2=(2\ell)^2=L^2$.

Comment: That works for $4\ell^2$ but what if you have $4*r^2$.  Is it possible to start with $4*r^2$, where r is half the length of a side of the square, and simplify to $L^2$?

Comment: @akaitora, you are free to use whatever symbol you like for the half length.