# Why does integrating perimeter not give area of equilateral triangle?

Tags: integration, triangles, area

I want to derive the formula for the area of an equilateral triangle by integrating a simple formula for its perimeter. Here's my attempt that doesn't work.

I want to know why it doesn't work.

```
3 * side = perimeter

area = integral of perimeter wrt side

area = 3/2 * side^2
```

But I know that the real formula is `area = (sqrt(3)/4) * s^2`.

So what's wrong with the way I'm trying to get the formula?

Cheers

Comment: You might find [this question, and it's answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298970/integrating-a-squares-perimeter-to-get-its-area) relevant.

Comment: It works only with circles :)
\
I think you have to improve your intuition about integrals and derivatives, before you start asking why the perimeter of a square is not $2L$ because area is $L^2$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: What does your arrogant comment add to his/her understanding?

Comment: @Raffaele: You are incorrect. It also works with the square, for example. It seems that your intuition needs some improvement as well.